# Is it a good practice to have every collection be a sub-collection of users?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

There are certain limits imposed on collections in Firestore. For example, one of such limits is:

> Maximum write rate to a collection in which documents contain sequential values in an indexed field - **500 per second**

So an app with sufficiently big traffic is going to run into this problem.

As I understand, because all the subcollections are treated as stand-alone collections, and their quotas are calculated separately, the solution to this would be to have a single "root" collection, say `users`, and have all the other collections be subcollections of `users`:

```
users/
  books/
  articles/
  // etc..
```

Am I understanding all of this correctly? And if so, is it a good practice to have such a root collection above all the subcollections?

Comment: I'm not an expert, so I'm leaving this as a comment rather than an answer, but, for what it's worth, your logic and approach sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: For whoever voted to close this question as opinion-based. This is a legitimate question about scalability and how Firestore is intended to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This limit (and most other write limits on Firestore) comes from the fact that it needs to write the data to disk (in multiple data centers) and there's a limit to how much data a disk+network can write in close proximity. This affects documents themselves, but much more so: it affects the indexes that exist on those documents. If Firestore needs to update values that are close to one another in an index in close succession, that leads to so-called hotspots.

If you never need to query across those subcollections, then indeed: storing the docs in separate (sub)collections will increase the write throughput - or better: reduce the chances of write hotspots.

If you ever need to query across those subcollections, and thus need a collection group index on them, then there's no difference between a single collection or multiple (sub)collections as that index then becomes your hotspot.

Comment: Ah, I never thought about the collection group index, thanks for the insight!